# Pandas handling local time change slow for `read_csv`

Tags: pandas

When reading from a large CSV file with a change in the time zone offset (daylight saving) the `parse_dates` becomes slow. Can you suggest how I should handle this? For some work, I do convert to 'UTC' but I also need to work with the original local time. Is there a way to force the parsing of the column to `datetime64[ns]` and not  `datetime64[ns, <offset>]`? I think that adding the column time offset might have been an improvement https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16898. I might need the original naive timestamp.

```
pd.__version__
'0.24.2'
```

## With time offset change

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""date_time
2018-11-27 04:57:10+01:00
2018-11-27 04:57:10+02:00
2018-11-27 04:57:10+02:00
2018-11-27 04:57:10+02:00""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=",", parse_dates =['date_time'])
```

Output

```
df.date_time

0    2018-11-27 04:57:10+01:00
1    2018-11-27 04:57:10+02:00
2    2018-11-27 04:57:10+02:00
3    2018-11-27 04:57:10+02:00
Name: date_time, dtype: object
```

I think I want `dtype: datetime64[ns]`

## No time offset change

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""date_time
2018-11-27 04:57:10+02:00
2018-11-27 04:57:10+02:00
2018-11-27 04:57:10+02:00
2018-11-27 04:57:10+02:00""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=",", parse_dates =['date_time'])
```

Output

```
df.date_time

0   2018-11-27 04:57:10+02:00
1   2018-11-27 04:57:10+02:00
2   2018-11-27 04:57:10+02:00
3   2018-11-27 04:57:10+02:00
Name: date_time, dtype: datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(120)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your data changes hour offset in the middle, a regular string-based parsing approach will simply relay those offset changes as different unnamed time zones. The issue with Pandas is that it [can't represent a column as containing more than one time zone](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-csv-mixed-timezones), instead representing the column as `object`. To fix this, we need to explicitly convert each value to a single named time zone. This enables Pandas to use, e.g., `datetime64[ns, America/New_York]` as the type for the column, which it will do automatically if all the values in the column have the same time zone. The changing hour offsets are defined by that time zone definition, so the information is preserved. The downside is that you have to know the named time zone to go with your data.

I've played with a few approaches to evaluate the speed differences. For whatever reason, the built-in Pandas function `to_datetime()` is very slow. I would, instead, suggest an alternative approach depending on your data, performing the text-to-datetime conversion yourself. Create a Python `datetime` object in your favorite way, apply a time zone, then convert to Pandas `Timestamp` type. If you're comfortable with the external `ciso8601` library, which has fast string-to-ISO8601 parsing, you can use the approach below. You'll also need the popular `pytz` library with its time zone definitions.

Let's assume you have a CSV file named `filename` and it has a `Timestamp` column with ISO8601 timestamps in it.

```py
import ciso8601
import pandas as pd
import pytz

TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'

def custom_parse(val):
    iso_time = ciso8601.parse_datetime(val)
    tz_time = iso_time.astimezone(pytz.timezone(TIME_ZONE))
    pd_time = pd.Timestamp(tz_time)
    return pd_time

dt = pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates=['Timestamp'], date_parser=custom_parse)
```

If you don't want to use `ciso8601`, you could substitute the `iso_time =` step with a regex-based parsing step, or [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), etc. Almost anything will be faster than `to_datetime()` provided by Pandas.